# How to fix the WindowManager exception in media player?

Tags: android

android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@405cab80 is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: are you using activity group?

Comment: yes. i m using                                             MyLiveGroupActivity extends TabGroupActivity{
      
        startChildActivity("MyLiveActivity", new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyLiveActivity.class));

Comment: use Actvitiy.getparent()

Comment: i m using context .  any idea???   boolean goToMyActivity;
boolean popActivity;                                          Context context;
     MyDialogOnClickListener(Context context){
      this.context = context;
     }
     MyDialogOnClickListener(boolean popActivity,Context context){
      this.popActivity = popActivity;
      this.context = context;
     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is you are trying to use "this" reference to your context which is causing the problem in ActivityGroup. Instead of this, this.Context replace it with the object of Activity Group.

For Example, consider your class which extends ActivityGroup class. You could have created a  **object** for that class.

Example:

```
   public class Home extends ActivityGroup {
public static Home Home_Group;
ArrayList<View> home_history;

    public void onCreate()
{

}
```

As you can see here I have created a object for my Home class as **Home_Group**.
Now, define the context using this object. Something like this,

```
    Context xc=null;
    xc=Home_Group;
```